# Change other worksheet based on a dropdown list value from main sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to program a button that could change a specific worksheet from a value on a dropdown list from my main sheet.

My main sheet is "RESUMO". I have a button on another sheet ("IOP-F&I") that has this code to show the sheet.

```vb
Sub VistaCliente()

    Sheets("VistaCliente").Visible = True
    Sheets("VistaCliente").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Condicoes.Show
   
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to program is that the button leads to a sheet based on a dropdown list that is on the cell E7 from "RESUMO".

I wrote this on the main sheet "RESUMO". It works the way I want for this, but I don't know how to make it to when I run the macro to open these specific sheets.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If [E7] = "DNN" Then
    Sheets("VistaCliente_DNN").Visible = True
Else
    Sheets("VistaCliente_DNN").Visible = False
End If

If [E7] = "SESA" Then
    Sheets("VistaCliente_SESA").Visible = True
Else
    Sheets("VistaCliente_SESA").Visible = False
End If

If [E7] = "SOM" Then
    Sheets("VistaCliente_SOM").Visible = True
Else
    Sheets("VistaCliente_SOM").Visible = False
End If

If [E7] = "SATE" Then
    Sheets("VistaCliente_SATE").Visible = True
Else
    Sheets("VistaCliente_SATE").Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand your actual question or problem. Is it to hide all sheets except Resumo? Where your Button and Combo Box is located. Is this display of the userform where it is located - `Condicoes.Show`?

```
Sub VistaCliente()
MySelectedSheet = Worksheets("Resumo").Cells(7, 5)
For Each sh In Worksheets
    TempName = sh.Name
    If InStr(1, TempName, MySelectedSheet) > 0 Then
        sh.Visible = True
        sh.Select
        sh.Range("A1").Select
    ElseIf sh.Name <> "Resumo" Then
        sh.Visible = False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! Works like charm! Thank you so much!
Is there anyway I can dm you somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This can work for you:

```
Sub VistaCliente()
Dim Thisws As String
Thisws = Sheets("Resumo").Range("E7").Value

Sheets(Thisws).Visible = True
Sheets(Thisws).Select
Range("A1").Select
Condicoes.Show
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response!
I tried but it returns "Subject out of Range".
When I click on the button/macro "VistaCliente" I would like that it would get a value from the dropdown list that I already have and open a specific worksheet

Comment: What line does arise the error? What is the exact name of the sheet where cell E7 is the dropdown list?

Comment: Line 9. The name of the sheet where the dropdown list is, is "RESUMO". But the macro is assigned to a button on sheet "IOP-F&I. Don't know if helps but thanks

Comment: The code is 8 lines, there is no line 9. Please, debug it and post what part is highlighted on yellow

Comment: Sorry.
Sheets(Thisws).Visible = True
The error is on that line

Comment: That means there is no sheet named as the value specified in cell E7 of your sheet RESUMO. Check your worksheet names and make sure they fit the dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick up an event that can trigger start and execution of your code. If you want a Button, you need to add it to your sheet as an Axtive-X control. By a simple double click on the object you Sub will be generated as code behind sheet. like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MySelectedSheet = Cells(7, 5)
Sheets(MySelectedSheet).Visible = True
Sheets(MySelectedSheet).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

This read the value of cell E7 to variable used code and use the value to identify sheet name that is is working with.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response!
I already have a macro assigned to a button, which I've posted on the initial problem. But I wanted that the button could get the value from the dropdown list that I have on cell E7 and make a specific worksheet unhidden. I don't know if I'm making my self clear, sorry for the english

Comment: If you have a button that starts code in a module you might need to find, or referee to the worksheet object where the linked cell (property of combo box) is found - And that is how your combo box is set up. I will post you another answer according to your changes.